# Left Outer Join in Linq not working

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm trying to do a left outer join in Linq but the below code is not working

```
 var result = from dataRows1 in agdt.AsEnumerable()
              join dataRows2 in hwt.AsEnumerable()
              on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("HWID") 
              where ((dataRows2.Field<string>("HWID") == null) && 
                    (dataRows1.Field<string>("TYPE")=="a"))
              select dataRows1;
```

Without the where clauses I receive about 37000 rows and with it I receieve 0. The `agdt` table has 12000 rows and the `hwt` table has 6000. This is getting very frustrating. Can someone please help?

Comment: Need more info. Structure of table, some sample data.

Comment: You could try :dataRows2.IsNull("HWID")

Comment: Hubert, thats not making any difference. Almo, here is the test row that I am inserting. The table structure is the same for both tables:

            DataRow dr = agdt.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = "atest";
            dr["TYPE"] = "a";
            dr["TITLE"] = "outlier";
            dr["URL"] = "url"   ;
            dr["STAMP"] = changestamp;
            agdt.Rows.Add(dr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) method call.

From what I understand from your query, it should look something like:

```
var result = from dataRows1 in agdt.AsEnumerable()
          join dataRows2 in hwt.AsEnumerable()
          on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("HWID") 
          into groupJoin
          from leftOuterJoinedTable in groupJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where (leftOuterJoinedTable == null && 
                (dataRows1.Field<string>("TYPE")=="a"))
          select dataRows1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this in essence would be the same as running the following SQL query

SELECT 
     DR1.*
FROM DataRows1 DR1
INNER JOIN DataRows2 DR2
     ON DR1.ID=DR2.HWID
WHERE
     DR2.HWID IS NULL
     AND
     DR1.Type='a'

Essentially your LINQ is doing an inner join and then executing the where. To truly do a left join, see the link

[LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)